# If $a$ commutes with $b$, does $a^{-1}$ commute with $b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$a,b$ are group elements. If $a$ commutes with $b$, does $a^{-1}$ commute with $b$?

And how can I prove this?

Comment: $a^{-1}b = a^{-1}baa^{-1}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89079/prove-the-centralizer-of-an-element-in-group-g-is-a-subgroup-of-g is more or less a duplicate, or at least of interest

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
ab=ba
&\Leftrightarrow aba^{-1}=baa^{-1}\\
&\Leftrightarrow aba^{-1}=b\\
&\Leftrightarrow a^{-1}aba^{-1}=a^{-1}b\\
&\Leftrightarrow ba^{-1}=a^{-1}b
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 14):

Note that if $$ab=ba$$ then multiply previous relation by $a^{-1}$ from the left to get: $$b=e_Gb=(a^{-1}a)b=a^{-1}(ab)=a^{-1}(ba)=a^{-1}ba$$ Now , again multiply previous relation by $a^{-1}$ from the right to get: $$ba^{-1}=(a^{-1}ba)a^{-1}=a^{-1}b(aa^{-1})=a^{-1}be_G=a^{-1}b$$

Answer (score 11):

More generally, for subsets $U\subseteq G$, the **normalizer** of $U$ is defined as
$$ N_G(U):=\{\,g\in G\mid gU=Ug\,\}$$
and is a subgroup of $G$ because

- $eU =U=Ue$ trivially
- $gU=Ug $ and $hU=Uh$ implies $(gh)U=g(hU)=(gU)h=(Ug)h=U(gh)$
- $gU=Ug$ implies $g^{-1}U=g^{-1}Ugg^{-1}=g^{-1}gUg^{-1}=Ug^{-1}$

that is $N_G(U)$ is nonempty and closed under multiplication and taking inverses.

You are concerned with the special case $U=\{b\}$ and the claim $a\in N_G(U)\implies a^{-1}N_G(U)$.

Answer (score 2):

@parsec Now you have seen all the answers you probably can prove that *any* power $a^n$ commutes with $b$, in other words, the group generated by your $a$ and $b$, $<a,b>$,  is *abelian*.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! I've proved the $a^n$ case before but I didn't realize the connection.