# Showing if $G$ is a group then the centralizer of an element is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given: Let $G$ be an arbitrary group, and let $a\in G$. The centralizer of $a$ is defined as

$$C(a)=\{x\in G: xa=ax\}.$$

Question: Show that if $G$ is a group and $a\in G$, then $C(a)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

My work: Suppose $a$ has the identity element. Then let $xa=ax$ and $e$ be the identity element such that , $xea = xae = xa = ax$. Since we now know that both have the same identity element, and $C(a)$ is an element of $G$, it tells us that it gives the same identity element

Could anyone verify this for me please? if it is wrong, then could you correct it please?

Thank you

Comment: $C(a)$ is a set, not an element of $G$.

What you want to show is that $ea=ae$, which is trivial. Then show if $xa=ax, xb=bx\implies (ab^{-1})x=x(ab^{-1})$.

Comment: Could you show me how ea=ae,which is the identity element ,and the inverse?

Comment: By definition $ea=a=ae$.

Comment: that's what i showed and i was told to explain more. how? all i can think of is ae=ea=a.

Comment: Let me expound in an answer.

Comment: Also $a$ cannot "have an element," as it is not a set, only $C(a)$ is a set in this.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89079/prove-the-centralizer-of-an-element-in-group-g-is-a-subgroup-of-g

Answer (score 2):

To show the set $C(a)$ is a group, it needs to be non-empty and satisfy $x,y\in C(a)\implies xy^{-1}\in C(a)$.

Firstly, $e\in C(a)$ because, **by definition** things in $C(a)$ are things that commute with $a$, i.e. $x\in G$ such that $ax=xa$. The identity, again **by definition** satisfies $ae=ea$, so $e\in C(a)$, and so it is non-empty.

**Edit:** in case you cannot see the proof all at once as in my original version, here is a more basic/less slick way. The slick proof is included at the end for completeness and those interested.

If $x,y\in C(a)$ then

$$xya=x(ya)$$

$$=x(ay)$$

since $ya=ay$

$$=(xa)y$$

by associativity

$$=axy$$

because $ax=xa$

hence $C(a)$ is closed under the group operation.

If $x\in C(a)$ then

$$ax^{-1}=x^{-1}xax^{-1}$$

since $xx^{-1}=e$

$$=x^{-1}axx^{-1}$$

since $ax=xa$

$$=x^{-1}a$$

since $x^{-1}x=e$

showing closure under inverses. Hence $xy^{-1}\in C(a)$ by definition of the set $C(a)$, so $C(a)$ is a subgroup.

---

For those interested in the original approach:

Let $x,y\in C(a)$ which we have already established is non-empty. Then

$$ayx^{-1}=yx^{-1}x(y^{-1}ay)x^{-1}$$

because $yx^{-1}=(xy^{-1})^{-1}$

$$=yx^{-1}x(y^{-1}ya)x^{-1}=yx^{-1}(xax^{-1})$$

since $ay=ya$ and $yy^{-1}=e$

$$=yx^{-1}a$$

since $ax=xa$ and $xx^{-1}=e$

hence

$$yx^{-1}a=ayx^{-1}$$

and we have shown $xy\in C(a)\implies yx^{-1}\in C(a)$ and again we have a subgroup.

So $C(a)$ again is a group by the same criterion.

Comment: I understand showing that the identity and the inverse exist. To show that the product of the element, would this be correct?(xy)a=x(ya)-->(xy)a=x(ay)--> (xy)a=(xa)y--->(xy)a=(ax)y-->(xy)a=a(xy) which shows that the product of elements in C(a) is C(a). wouldnt this be correct?

Comment: @chris yes, that's exactly what I wrote above. If you have questions on anything I haven't already written above, feel free to post them as well for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To show $C(a)$ is a subgroup, you need to show

- $C(a)$ contains the identity (of $G$)
- The inverse of any element in $C(a)$ is in $C(a)$
- The product of two elements in $C(a)$ is in $C(a)$

$C(a)$ is the set of all elements in $G$ that commute with $a$. Does the identity element commute with $a$?

If $g \in C(a)$, then $ga=ag$. To show $g^{-1}a=ag^{-1}$, see what happens when you multiply $g^{-1}a$ on the right by $e=gg^{-1}$.

If $g,h \in C(a)$, then $ga=ag$ and $ha=ah$. You want to show $(gh)a=a(gh)$. This follows immediately if you use what you know about $g$ and $h$.

Comment: ae=ea=a therefore the identity exists. doesnt this prove that C(a) contains the identity of G? or do i need to expand it further? if so, i honestly dont know how. and i understand the definition of subgroup

Comment: @chris Yes, that is enough to show that $C(a)$ contains the identity of $G$.